# Is there a way to have a global style for button in tcl?

Tags: tcl

So I have this type of button with this options.

```
button .but1 -text "Sample" -width 10 -height 2 -background $btnColor -activeforeground $actForegrd -state normal -activebackground $activbtnColor -relief flat -highlightthickness 0
```

is there a way to make a global variable with those options for button, I know about style configure, but in order to use style, I need to change my buttons to ttk::button and those don't have the same options as the regular button.

I try putting all the options in a string and pass it when creating a button but it doesn't work
example:

```
set style "-width 10 -height 2 -background $btnColor -activeforeground $actForegrd -state normal -activebackground $activbtnColor -relief flat -highlightthickness 0"
button .but1 $style
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two basic possibilities.

### 1. Use expansion

What you tried is *almost* right. Try this:

```
set style "-width 10 -height 2 -background $btnColor -activeforeground $actForegrd -state normal -activebackground $activbtnColor -relief flat -highlightthickness 0"
button .but1 {*}$style
```

The `{*}` (which entered Tcl in 8.5) makes what follows it be *expanded* to many arguments.

### 2. Use the option "database"

Instead, you can put all those values into the *option database* using the [`option` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/option.htm):

```
option add *.Button.width 10
option add *.Button.height 2
option add *.Button.background $btnColor
option add *.Button.activeForeground $actForegrd
option add *.Button.state normal
option add *.Button.activeBackground $activbtnColor
option add *.Button.relief flat
option add *.Button.highlightThickness 10
## You can also pull the above from a separate file with:
# option readfile ~/thefile.opts

button .but1
```

Using the option database right and well is tricky, but it lets you set the defaults for many widgets at once (or a single one, or just widgets that are children of a particular window, or  of a class of windows, or …) You'd be truly splitting the style from the code.

I wouldn't normally have the `state` set by this mechanism though, as that's more of a semantic option; if a button is going to be disabled or not really *does* matter to code (just as the callback to run when that happens is another one I'd not set via options).

---

It should be noted that the Ttk style/theme mechanism largely supersedes this, as it allows for much more substantial modifications and cleaner runtime switching between them. But there are a number of effects that are quite a bit harder to do that way; we still maintain the classic `button`, etc. for a reason.