# Change the font and its size in a Tcltk GUI

Tags: r, user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can I change the default font and its size from a menu in a GUI I'm creating using Tcltk? The example below has only one menu called 'File', but in my GUI, It will have more than that. So all of them have to be re-sized. Is there any way to do that for my entire GUI?

Thank you in advance!

```
require(tcltk)
readCsv <- function(){
  myval <- tkgetOpenFile()
  mydata <- read.csv(paste(as.character(myval), collapse = " "))
  assign("myData", mydata, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

tt <- tktoplevel()
topMenu <- tkmenu(tt)           
tkconfigure(tt, menu = topMenu) 
fileMenu <- tkmenu(topMenu, tearoff = FALSE)
tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Quit", command = function() tkdestroy(tt))
tkadd(fileMenu, "command", label = "Load", command = function() readCsv())
tkadd(topMenu, "cascade", label = "File", menu = fileMenu)
tkfocus(tt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default font for menus is a *named* font; `TkMenuFont` on most platforms (and `menu` on OSX, where you really shouldn't change it). This is usually mapped to the correct system default font for menus. However, if you do want to change it, you're still recommended to use a named font (which is what is used in a font object in R TclTk) following the pattern [on this page](http://www.sciviews.org/_rgui/tcltk/Fonts.html) except that you're applying the font to a menu widget instead of a label.

```
# Example to show how to do it
fontMenu <- tkfont.create(family="times",size=24,weight="bold",slant="italic")
fileMenu <- tkmenu(topMenu, tearoff = FALSE, font = fontMenu)
```

The only platform where you shouldn't do this at all is OSX, where menus work rather differently (except at the script level; there's a *lot* of differences being hidden under the covers!)

Comment: How about the topmenu name? I saw that it works perfectly for what is inside the menu, but not the menu itself. Another questions is, can I use the same syntax for ttklabelframe?

Comment: For menus, it depends on the platform. With ttklabelframe, it sets the font via the style/theme. Style authoring is… rather trickier. (I've no idea how to phrase it in R, and not much more idea than that in other languages that use Tk either.) The usual recommendation is to not change the style; you usually produce better looking applications overall by having a consistent system theme…

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using the option database.

See this question for an example showing the option database for use with a button, but works the same for menus:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20960107/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-global-style-for-button-in-tcl

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response. I've seen this example before, but I'm not sure on how to apply to the language I'm using. As you could see, it's a little bit different from what we see in the example. Sorry if this is basic, but I'm new in R and TclTk language! So any other ideas?